# how to install html agility pack and add a reference to the dll on Windows Vista

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll, html-agility-pack

I have downloaded HTML Agility pack, and after extracting I can see that there are sub folders with name NET 20, NET 40, NET 40 Client, NET 45, sl3-wp, sl4-windowsphone71, sl5, winrt45.

I have downloaded Microsoft Visual 2010. Sadly, I cannot proceed further( i.e., I cannot install Html agility pack in Vista and add a reference to the dll. I am new in the use of HTML Agility pack and I have the code prepared by my friend to run. Will be much thankful if you could provide some insights. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to install HTMLAgilityPack is though Nuget Package manager.  If you havent already added it to Visual Studio you can grab Nuget from here

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c

Nuget will download and install packages (DLLs) for you. You can find Agility Pack Nuget here:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/htmlagilitypack

Comment: Thanks for providing the info. I've tried to install the first link you have provided to me. But, I got an error message saying that "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products". How to proceed? What are the requirements to open NuGet Package Manager?

Comment: Have a look at the FAQ's http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq because your on Vista you'll need to manually Install powershell first.